# ASP MVC 3 logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, caching

I have problem with logout in asp.mvc.
User can press back button, and he will see last visited page.

I performed some search and found solution like this:

```
this.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-1));
this.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
this.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

but I should add it to each page to make it work.

Is there some way to disable cache for all GET requests for all controllers in mvc application, and then enable it for some of them for example with attribute or custom filter?

Comment: Of course he can. Why shouldn't he? However, he can not perform any actions. Changing cache settings only affect the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not much work to get it working globally.  We I have done in the past is create a class that derives from ActionFilter and then add it as a global action filter in global.asax. Also note that actually forcing all browsers to reload is not trivial.  Even the below code doesn't always work with Safari, which often has to be tricked via an empty onload of the body tag or similar.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Web.Mvc;

 /// <summary>
 /// Action filter that instructs the page to expire.
 /// </summary>
 public class PageExpirationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// The OnActionExecuted method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The current ActionExecutedContext. </param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders();
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0");
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=3, max=993");
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    }
 }
```

If you want to be able to exclude certain pages, another attribute could be created that you can apply to controllers or methods.  Your OnActionExecuting() can check if the attribute is present:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class AllowCachingAttribute : Attribute 
{ 
}
```

Approximate Code to add to OnActionExecuting

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Web.Mvc;

 /// <summary>
 /// Action filter that instructs the page to expire.
 /// </summary>
 public class PageExpirationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// The OnActionExecuted method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The current ActionExecutedContext. </param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

       bool skipCache = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowCachingAttribute), true)
                || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowCachingAttributee), true);

       if (!skipCache)
       {

       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders();
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0");
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=3, max=993");
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfect for me! This is exactly what I was searching for!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Utilities class and add a public static method that does the above code and then call it.  Then in the Methods of you controllers, call the Utilities method.  I will provide some code:

```
namespace App
{
    public class Utility
    {
        public static void SetResponsAttributes(HttpResponseBase theResponseObject)
        {
            if (theResponseObject == null) return;

            theResponseObject.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-1));
            theResponseObject.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            theResponseObject.Cache.SetNoStore(); 
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to call this method in each action of each controller. I am looking for some way to add this by default, and then remove where I want to.

Comment: Gotcha.....I tried global.asax.cs  But Response is not available in that context.  Let's see what else we can do

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a session flag to indicate the logged in indicator and wrap the entire view content inside an if block. Abandon the session on log out.

Comment: this won't work, because browser loads last page from the cache. It doesn't even make any requests to server for rendering page. I am using FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); and Session.Abandon(); but it does not prevent user from returning to last page with "back" button.